# October CMS: AJAX form

Tags: ajax, laravel, octobercms

My aim is to update a partial to show course dates when a date range is specified and submitted.

I have a function that works as expected.

- user selects a start date
- user selects an end date
- the user clicks search
- results are logged to the console

Here is the function

```
function onFetchDataFromServer()
{
    $course = Course::findOrFail( $this->param('id') );

    $start = Input::get('start_date');

    $end = Input::get('end_date');

    $dates = $course->coursemetas->whereBetween('date', array($start, $end));

    return $dates;
}
```

Here is the markup

```
<form class="row gx-3 align-items-center" data-request="onFetchDataFromServer" data-request-success="console.log(data)"">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg pxp-has-left-border">
        <div class="input-group mb-3 mb-lg-0">
            <span class="input-group-text"><span class="fa fa-calendar-o"></span></span>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="startPicker" name="start_date" placeholder="Choose a start date">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg pxp-has-left-border">
        <div class="input-group mb-3 mb-lg-0">
            <span class="input-group-text"><span class="fa fa-calendar-o"></span></span>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="endPicker" name="end_date" placeholder="Choose an end date">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-auto">
        <button type="submit">Search dates</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

So the rather than logging the results to the console, I now would like to update a partial.

I have a partial in the view called 'course/metas'.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this. Check the [documents here](https://docs.octobercms.com/2.x/ajax/update-partials.html#pushing-partial-updates).

**This is for a page's PHP section:**

```
function onFetchDataFromServer()
{
    $course = Course::findOrFail( $this->param('id') );

    $start = Input::get('start_date');

    $end = Input::get('end_date');

    $dates = $course->coursemetas->whereBetween('date', array($start, $end));

    $this['dates'] = $dates;

    return [
        '#myDiv' => $this->renderPartial('coursemetas')
    ];
}
```

**This is for component plugin:**

```
function onFetchDataFromServer()
{
    $course = Course::findOrFail( $this->param('id') );

    $start = Input::get('start_date');

    $end = Input::get('end_date');

    $dates = $course->coursemetas->whereBetween('date', array($start, $end));

    $this->page['dates'] = $dates;

    return [
        '#myDiv' => $this->renderPartial('@coursemetas')
    ];
}
```

Note the @ sign sent with the `renderPartial` as this tells the framework to look inside the plugin folder for the partial. Or you can specify the partial path by component and partial name like this `return $this->renderPartial('course::coursemetas');`.

Comment: okay so i have done the following:

- added the partial ```coursemetas``` to my page layout

but if i used @coursemetas in the function it returns exception:
'The partial 'coursemetas' is not found.' loads without the '@' just not with the reponse.

Comment: i am doing this within the PHP tab and not in a component

Comment: @Jakef19 Aaaaah you don't specify that.  I will update the answer. In your theme under partials you have a partial called metas.htm? Or is it called coursemetas.htm?

Comment: Ahh sorry! It’s called coursemetas.htm

Comment: @Jakef19 Did you ever get this to work? Did you need more help?